# Why is the probability of selection in K-Means|| inversely related to the quantization error?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, error, k-means

In the first step of [K-means Parallel](http://www.utdallas.edu/~hschweitzer/restricted/teach/currentdr/Handouts/kmeans-parallel.pdf), every point $x_i$ is added to the initial cluster centers $U$ with probability $p_i$, as shown below:

[image: p_i = l * dist^2(x, U) / e_j]

I can understand why a high oversampling factor $l$ and a larger distance from the cluster centers would be desirable traits to have in a new point in our set of cluster centers.

However, I don't understand why the quantization error $e_j$ is in the denominator. This means that, when the quantization error is high (initially), points will have a lower probability of being added to $U$, even though we need to add more points to reduce the quantization error. However, once we add more points to $U$, our quantization error grows smaller, and the probability of adding future points $x_i$ to $U$ increases!

This seems really counterintuitive to me. I'd greatly appreciate some help in understanding what is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$e_j = \sum_i \operatorname{dist}^2(x_i, U).$$ It’s just a normalization factor, so that the expected number of points sampled at each step is $l$ – when the quantization is worse, the divisor is larger but so are the numerators, so it all evens out. In the document you linked, the “revised selection procedure” makes this explicit by sampling exactly $l$ points.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. I didn't realize there was such a direct connection between the numerator and denominator.